# Django display filefield in Template

Tags: django

I want to display and audio stored in filefield but the links comes up dead

```
#template
{% for audios in Audios %}
<audio controls>
    <source src="{{ audios.Audio_File.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
{% endfor %}

#settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

#urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Okay. Could you please check in the shell if there is an audio file URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate my life

i missed the $ in one of my urls.py

what i had

```
url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
```

what i changed to

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

It took me more than 24 hours to figure it out but i still dont know why only the files that i wanted to get were affected

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="{{audios.Audio_File.url}}" type="audio/{{audios.Audio_File.type}}">

  
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

At least we will know if the browser is supporting the audio and then we will debug it from there.

Comment: Doesnt work the link {{audio.Audio_File.url}} itself is dead

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should first configure your static and media in settings

```
BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
ROOT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


import os.path
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'static/')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

)
```

then just put some file in static and try to access it through browser, then check your Audio_File.url so it's generating properly

Comment: where does ROOT_PATH come from in your example? ty!

Comment: Thank you for pointing, i've fixed that